# InDesign: Change Layout of Overridden Frames by Master Page

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, master-page

I'm using InDesign to format a teacher's guide. Each activity will be based on an Activity Master Page (call it B).

So I set up B with the frames I want to appear on each activity page. Then, to add content, I override the master. This all works out well, but if I want to make a layout change to all the activities at once, modifying Master B does nothing to the activity pages because those have already overridden the master.

How can I set up my document so that I can quickly make layout changes to a group of pages all at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tested to be sure I'm correct (we used this method at a client for which I worked some years ago generating school curricula) and in fact it works for me in InDesign CC.

Masterpage laid out, with filler text in text boxes.

Override *just* the textframe item (Cntrl/Cmd + Shift + mouseclick) ***not*** the whole masterpage. ***Do not move the text frame at all*** on the local spread.

Enter new local text into the text frame directly on the target spreads - again, being careful to ***not alter*** the location or size of the *textframe* itself, *just* the textual content - no problem.

Return to masterpage and alter text boxes layout - no problem.

Return to target spread - new layout retaining local text - no problem.

Masterpage X
[image]

Spread w/ X Master applied, item over-rides on one red line and on text box - new content entered into text box with ***no*** *other changes* to text box:
[image]

Return to Master X - alter text frame layout:
[image]

Return to target spread - here we see locally-entered spread text still in place, *but* layout has changed with Master X *as expected*.
[image]

If you accidentally ***do*** alter the text frame location or size on the spread with that item over-ridden, that item will no longer update with the changes to the master, unless you then re-apply the Master - which would defeat the purpose of this workflow.

Overall - your method as proposed does work - if you're adequately careful.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's amazing, thank you! I was overriding the entire master on the page, rather than just the frames to which I added content. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite the purpose of master pages. I mean it sort of is, but once you start making overrides, the link is broken and any updates to the B master will not apply to those pages with master overrides.

You may need to critically adjust your workflow and only include fixed-position elements on the master pages, then you'll simply not need to do overrides. There's not enough detail provided to properly suggest alternatives.